# Whitespace changes layout in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I was having a curious problem that I finally found a solution to, but I'm not sure why it happens. I have a page that is being generated by PHP, so the resulting HTML is not always nicely formatted. Here's the relevant code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {background-color: #99ccff;}
            div#content {
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-align: center;
            }
            div#results_header {
                background-color: white;
                display: inline-block;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                margin: 5px 9px 0;
                padding-left: 18px;
                padding-top: 5px;
                text-align: left;
                border-bottom: 1px solid;
            }
            div.header {
                display: inline-block;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
            }
            div#ships {
                background-color: white;
                display: inline-block;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                height: 180px;
                margin: 0 9px 9px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                padding-left: 18px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            div.status {width: 10px;}
            div.name {width: 260px;}
            div.flag {width: 40px;}
            div.type {width: 50px;}
            div.sconum {width: 70px;}
            div.call_sign {width: 80px;}
            div.imo_number {width: 70px;}
            div.upseq {width: 140px;}
            div.photo {width: 50px;}
            div.my_photo {width: 50px;}
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content" style="width: 880px;">
            <div id="results_header" style="width: 840px;">
                <div class="name header">Name</div>
                <div class="flag header">Flag</div>
                <div class="type header">Type</div>
                <div class="sconum header">SCONUM</div>
                <div class="call_sign header">Call Sign</div>
                <div class="imo_number header">IMO #</div>
                <div class="upseq header">UPSEQ</div>
                <div class="photo header">Photo</div>
                <div class="my_photo header">My Photo</div>
            </div>
            <div id="ships" style="width: 840px;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I formatted it for readability (the CSS is actually in an external file, for instance). The page is actually generated by PHP so it doesn't look nearly as pretty as this. Therein lies the problem. What I posted above displays fine and consistent in all browsers. When I remove the whitespace before the "ships" div, it is misaligned in Chrome (Firefox looks fine, haven't had a chance to test in IE yet).

```
    <body>
        <div id="content" style="width: 880px;">
            <div id="results_header" style="width: 840px;">
                <div class="name header">Name</div>
                <div class="flag header">Flag</div>
                <div class="type header">Type</div>
                <div class="sconum header">SCONUM</div>
                <div class="call_sign header">Call Sign</div>
                <div class="imo_number header">IMO #</div>
                <div class="upseq header">UPSEQ</div>
                <div class="photo header">Photo</div>
                <div class="my_photo header">My Photo</div>
            </div>
<div id="ships" style="width: 840px;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Again, easily fixed, but I'm curious why this is happening at all.

Comment: The content. I don't care about the source.

Comment: Did you test it with the code you posted? Because I can't reproduce it. I can make it misalign in several ways, but I don't know if that's what's happening in your case. Also, in what way is it misaligned? Is `#ships` slightly off to the left, or off to the right?

Comment: It's been solved, but yes, I tested that exact code. The results_header was appearing 1 pixel more left than the ships div. If it matters, I was using vim as my editor.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I posted it. I made results_header and ships regular blocks and it all works.

Comment: I asked about the exact misalignment because it could also have been the `#results_header` that was actually off, since that was also an inline-block... But that doesn't matter now that it's all fixed. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's styled as an inline block. As it's inline, whitespace is significant. Use display:block; to avoid this.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to matter how MUCH whitespace I add. If I add a single tab or 100 tabs, it looks the same.

Comment: Also, even in the second case there's still whitespace (the newline between the closing and opening `div` tags). Adding more whitespace shouldn't matter. Even so, @Derek, your use of `display: inline-block`, on both `#ships` and `#results_header` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: That's because in HTML, multiple spaces are changed into 1 space. Try writing <p>Hello             World</p> with 10 spaces (as that one was!) - it will collapse into 1.